# Convention for maven properties: "dot case" or "camel case"?

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, camelcasing

Using java and `Maven`, what is the convention for maven properties?

I am posting 2 examples here, both of which are in widespread usage. Which one is correct, according to convention?

**Example A**

```
<properties>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
    <log4j2.version>2.0.2</log4j2.version>
</properties>
```

**Example B**

```
<properties>
    <hibernateVersion>4.3.8.Final</hibernateVersion>
    <hsqldbVersion>2.3.2</hsqldbVersion>
    <log4j2Version>2.0.2</log4j2Version>
</properties>
```

Edit:

Here is a link to a [Maven Properties Guide](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide). Some examples of maven properties include `${project.build.directory}` (dot case) and `${project.build.outputDirectory}` (both dot case and camel case).

And the official documentation [Maven POM Reference](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties) suggests an example property named `<someVar>` (camel case).

Comment: Try asking on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: While it's pretty common to use camelCase in XML tag names, all of the projects I've worked on use what you're (incorrectly) calling snake case (snake_case_is_like_this). This is probably since in an actual `.properties` file, you'd use a java package name as a prefix for your properties, so you'd have `com.mydomain.mypackage.myclass.myproperty` as the property key.

Comment: @beerbajay Thanks for the input. Problem with camelcase is that it seems to conflict with some built in maven properties, like `project.build.sourceEncoding` and `project.version`

Comment: @Bohemian Programmers Exchange, really? this is not a "conceptual" question - it is concrete in the context of maven dependencies for java projects. Can't see that it's not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Is this not just a matter of taste?

Comment: Only in the absence of a defined convention... is there such a convention? Please don't let me go away thinking this is another case of "big-endian" / "little-endian" ;)

Comment: Look at [Reflection Properties](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide#MavenPropertiesGuide-ReflectionProperties).

Comment: @Bohemian when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After reading the relevant documentation, the answer to this was clear all along.

The apparent conflict between `dot.case` and `camelCase` is that one is used to reference the *hierarchical structure within the POM* whilst the other is used for *variable naming*.

For example, let us look at `${project.build.outputDirectory}`. The dot notation here, as far as I can understand, refers to the pom structure where the variable is located, whereas the variable name itself is indeed in camel case.

```
<project>
  <build>
    <outputDirectory>/opt/foo</outputDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

In other words, the convention is as follows:

- To refer to variables located elsewhere in the POM, combine path segments such as `project` or `build` with the `.` separator, i.e. use **dot.case**. Examples:

  - `project.build.<variable>`
  - `maven.compiler.<variable>`
- To name the actual path segments, including the variable name itself (last segment), use **lowerCamelCase**. Examples:

  - `outputDirectory` (as in `project.build.outputDirectory`)
  - `target` (as in `maven.compiler.target`)

It is worth noting that most open source projects (including e.g. Spring Boot, pre-Gradle-migration - see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/abe95fa8a734291147fe74d29a90c137bb267d68/pom.xml)) use `.version` as a **path segment** and not as an addition to the variable name.

Consistency is the most important consideration. If your codebase is using `someDependencyVersion`, stick to that - else prefer `someDependency.version`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be late to the party, but here's my 2 cents.

Consider you may want to check if there's a newer versions available. You have to find each dependency reference within the pom to know the library's groupId and artifactId.

On the other hand, if you use a naming convention shown below, you immediately know whether the version is a reference to a groupId or an artifactId and you can just copy-paste it and search for latest version.

```
<properties>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.2.5</ch.qos.logback.version>
    <logstash-logback-encoder.version>6.6</logstash-logback-encoder.version>
</properties>
```